# Connector Type 6 Pin

Tags: connector

Maybe this is little bit off-topic, but I wanted to try to find out here what's the name of this connector?

[image]

I tried googling like "6 pin connector", "6 pin flat connector" but nothing like this comes out.

Comment: Look for "flat connector terminal block". And measure the width of the blades, as there are both 4.8mm and 6.3mm variants out there.

Comment: I beleive these people can give you a more exact identification;http://www.eagleday.com/muco6wila.html They specialize in "blade" connectors

Comment: @MEZLAW, thank you! I was able to find them by "Blade 6 pin connector".